# Implement OnTouchListener and onScrollLIstener together in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, ontouchlistener

I am using `ListView`. I want to have `onTouch` event for some condition and for other condition normal scrolling should be performed. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnTouchListener` to add a listener.

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
```

If you want filter for special action you can check in the `onTouch()` with something like:

```
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
   //Do something
 }
```

Comment: What about scrolling ?

Comment: Did you try `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {}`?

Comment: No. What to do inside `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {}` ?

Comment: Or do you want specifically listening for scrolling event, you can use: `listView.setOnScrollListener()`

Comment: I don't want to listen scrolling. For one condition i want to listen `onTouch` and for rest of the condtion, i want the list to be scroll.

Comment: To perform scrolling you can use `listview.smoothScrollByOffset(int)` or `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(int)`

Comment: I have disabled scrolling by overriding the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method. So right now my touch listener is working fine, in which i am doing some task if the condition matched. But if condition doesn't match, I want to enable the scrolling of `listview`.

Comment: may be i need to enable scrolling from `onTouch()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84545/discussion-between-joel-geiser-and-bunny).